# Links disappears when adding them to edit text an store them in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add links in my edit text in android . the edit text contains other text in addition to links written using html tag .

When adding the links in the edit text and saves the data to firebase real time database I found that the link has been disappeared.
I am using this code to my editText :

```java
 etContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Please share more code.

Comment: Please tell more about the issue, how is firebase concerned with this and what more code are you using to do the work.